# cellForRowAtIndexPath resource access

Tags: ios

I need to customize the separator lines of my UITableView and for that I have to access a resource (png file) inside the method cellForRowAtIndexPath like this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Some code here

myCustomSeparator.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"separator.png"]];

// Code ...

}
```

The thing is I heard it's not a good practice to access resources inside this method. Is it true ?

Comment: What memory are you talking about?

Comment: I meant accessing a resource.

Comment: I think you may be referring to the counsel that you shouldn't use the cell to store model data. But you can add view related elements there without incident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless, the standard way to achieve what you want is the below code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   // Some code here

   UIImageView *imagView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seprater.png"]];
   imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 1); // you can play with numbers here
   [customCell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

   // Code ...

   return customCell;
}
```